# What's the difference between the box-model bug and the new box-sizing CSS?

Tags: css

In days (long past for some, and still present for others) the box-model bug was a bane to their existence. The idea that an element's width included the margin, border, and padding was blasphemous and an abomination to their senses. So we got away from it after thousands of internet blogs about the box-model hack.

Now we get box-sizing, which will, wait for it, allow you to specify that a width contains the border, the margin, and the padding. We plaster a trendy new name for it, "CSS3 Flexbox," and now it's the freedom designers have been looking for.

For those logical people who saw the box-model bug as not the bug and the W3C as the actual bug, this comes as a surprise. A reintroduction of this so-called bug and now we call it an enhancement?

So can someone explain why this is different? I am honestly confused about this.

Comment: A "bug" is when an *implementation* does not correctly follow a *specification*. This says nothing about the design choice(s) of the *specification*.

Comment: @pst: Correct. It just so happens that the buggy implementation ended up becoming an [Ascended Glitch](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AscendedGlitch).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now we get box-sizing, which will, wait for it, allow you to specify that a width contains the border, the margin, and the padding. We plaster a trendy new name for it, "CSS3 Flexbox," and now it's the freedom designers have been looking for.

No, we call it the "border box" model. [Flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox) is a totally different thing; it is unrelated to the [`box-sizing` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0), which is used to tell a browser how to calculate the dimensions of a box.

> For those logical people who saw the box-model bug as not the bug and the W3C as the actual bug, this comes as a surprise. A reintroduction of this so-called bug and now we call it an enhancement?
>
> So can someone explain why this is different? I am honestly confused about this.

It used to be considered a bug for a long time because at the time, there was only the One True Box Model ([W3C content box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html)) which everybody had to follow when CSS was just beginning to pick up, and at that time [IE was the black sheep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug). But then [people — even those who hated IE's guts — *liked* this bug, and so border box sizing was added into the CSS3 spec as an option](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AscendedGlitch). Plain and simple.<sup>1</sup>

Note that IE5.x (and quirks mode IE<sup>2</sup>) will always continue to exhibit buggy behavior as per *any* version of the spec, and older versions of other browsers that didn't support `box-sizing` will always follow the original content box model in standards mode (and sometimes, but not always, in almost standards mode).

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Now there are at least two, the original W3C content box model and the "new" border box model. There's also a third [*padding box* model being explored by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing), but that's not really relevant to what we're talking about here, and it's at risk of being dropped from the CSS3 UI CR anyway.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Depending on whom you ask, this may be regarded as a "feature" instead, as the primary purpose of quirks mode is to *emulate* buggy browser rendering for use with *legacy code*, and it is not intended for use with new code.</sub>

Comment: "No, we call it the "border box" model. The flexible box is a totally different thing; it is unrelated to the box-sizing property used to tell a browser how to calculate the dimensions of a box." True. i was also thinking about another problem I had with spacing and the flexbox was on the mind. You talked about and explained what I was really meaning.

Comment: "But then people — even those who hated IE's guts — liked this bug, and so border box sizing was added into the CSS3 spec as an option. Plain and simple." This makes sense now. For the longest time, I have only seen people talking down about the box-model bug so I really didn't realize there was a calling for this BECAUSE people liked it. They always just seemed to say, "I hate IE, so I hate the box-model bug, the w3c way is the best." Thanks for clearing that up. And AFAIK, the box-sizing is supposed to be growing to include the Mozilla padding awa margin box but your sources might be better.

Comment: The Last Call draft of CSS3 UI says it may be dropped due to lack of implementations (currently only Mozilla has it). Then again, only time will tell...

Comment: Funny thing, reading an article from Paul Irish today about this. http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/   he discusses my opposition to the current box-model.